# nativescript Cannot find module 'platform'

Tags: nativescript, require

In Nativescript after-prepare hook, I want to find out the current platform that the nativescript is preparing for so that I can do different things. So I added

> require("platform");

But when I do `tns prepare android`, I always get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'platform'

When I tried adding `require("http");` above the `require("platform");`, `require("http");`does not give me error. What is the difference between these two cases? Why `require("platform");` fails but `require("http");` succeed?

Both http module and platform module are in tns-core-modules folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the TNS core modules inside the hooks. Depending on what your trying to do maybe it would be better to use gulp or something like it. Then create scripts in your package.json to do the processes you need for either platform and then run the nativescript process.

for example.

package.json

```
scripts": {
    "android-stuff": "gulp yourTask && tns run android",
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why TNS core modules can not be used inside the hooks?

Comment: The tns core modules are abstractions for Android and iOS. The hooks have more to do with the build processes and file systems. Check out https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-sass it uses the hooks to build sass.  hope that helps